# Approach to reduce writing the same boring code when working with permissions

Tags: android, oop, kotlin

Currently, I am writing a chat application for Android. Starting from 23 SDK and above, it needs some permissions which user has to allow, such as extreme important (my chat will use a location of creation of a particular chat) and just small features such as uploading images to Firebase storage (it needs the access to phone storage, therefore it needs appropriate permission).

I have the following interface for callbacks.

```
object PermissionUtils {

 interface PermissionAskListener {


        fun onPermissionGranted()
        /*
            User has already granted this permission
            The app must had been launched earlier and the user must had "allowed" that permission
         */


        fun onPermissionRequest()
        /*
            The app is launched FIRST TIME..
            We don't need to show additional dialog, we just request for the permission..

         */


        fun onPermissionPreviouslyDenied()
        /*
            The app was launched earlier and the user simply "denied" the permission..
            The user had NOT clicked "DO NOT SHOW AGAIN"
            We need to show additional dialog in this case explaining how "allowing this permission" would be useful to the user
         */


        fun onPermissionDisabled()
        /*
            The app had launched earlier and the user "denied" the permission..
            AND ALSO had clicked "DO NOT ASK AGAIN"
            We need to show Toask/alertdialog/.. to indicate that the user had denied the permission by checking do not disturb too...
            So, you might want to take the user to setting>app>permission page where the user can allow the permission..


         */

    }

fun checkForPermission(activity: Activity, permission: String, permissionAskListener: PermissionAskListener) {
//code omitted, here's the logic of calls listener members 
 }
}
```

And, I use it in code like this:

```
//calling from onCreate()
checkForPermission(
            this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            object : PermissionAskListener {
                override fun onPermissionGranted() {
                    showToast(getString(R.string.msg_permissions_granted), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    uplodAnImageToFirebase()

                }

                override fun onPermissionRequest() {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this@MainActivity, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), readStorage
                    )
                }

                override fun onPermissionPreviouslyDenied() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.title_permission_required))
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_permission_required))
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.action_allow)) { _, _ ->
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                this@MainActivity,
                                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                                readStorage
                            )
                        }
                        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.action_cancel)) { dialog, _ ->
                            dialog.cancel()
                            showToast(getString(R.string.msg_we_cant_give_functionality), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        }
                        .show()
                }

                override fun onPermissionDisabled() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.title_permission_disabled))
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_please_enable_permission))
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton(
                            getString(R.string.action_go_to_settings)
                        ) { _, _ -> startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS)) }
                        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.action_cancel)) { dialog, _ ->
                            dialog.cancel()
                            showToast(getString(R.string.msg_we_cant_give_functionality), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        }
                        .show()
                }
            }
        )
```

As you may see from code, only onPermissionGranted() do something particular, and either onPermissionPreviouslyDenied() and onPermissionDisabled() just saying to user boring and common things, which I want to incapsulate to some class that will create either dialogs for extra important things (like location; if permission denied I'd like to close entire app), and either just upload, which will just block functionality.

I know how to do such requests for permission and other stuff like it. I don't know how to create these classes with the dialogs - create enum that I pass whenever I call onDisabled/onPreviouslyDenied method from activity, or create Builder for it, or create Factory... if you TL;DR case, then just answer: 'How to reduce the same code in my case?'

Comment: There are a seemingly infinite number of [libraries to try to reduce some of this boilerplate](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/235?sort=created).

Comment: Thank, I now will take a look

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to create a `BaseActivity` class, and have your other activities in the app sub-class the `BaseActivity`.

Something like..

```
class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        checkForPermissions() // do your permission check code 
    }
}

class MainActivity: BaseActivity {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate() // calls BaseAcivitiy's onCreate, which triggers the checkForPermissions
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I would not guess to this. Thank you for broading my outlook!)

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare suggested in the comments, there is (here is [libraries to try to reduce some of this boilerplate](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/235?sort=created)) a lot of good libraries. I've chosen a [NoPermission library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6212). Maybe, it seems like an advertising, but I'm sure that this is not the worst library. Have a nice day!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use the following library:
https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

On the other hand, to avoid duplicate code, you can move to separate class the code related to dialog helper.

For instance: https://github.com/jpgpuyo/MVPvsMVVM/blob/one_dialog/app/src/main/java/upday/mvpvsmvvm/dialoghelper/DialogHelper.java

Comment: Thank for help, you are great: you didn't pass by, you helped me. But this library doesn't contains anything unusual. And DialogHelper too. But, in any case, how could you know what I know?) In any case, stay nice as you are now, jpgpuyo!)

Comment: @DanielJorn About the library, it helps to reduce boilerplate code, it allows to put your permissions logic where you want and it helps to avoid possible issues. 

About DialogHelper, it is only a litte sample, but imagine if you start to put AlertDialog along all the code and then you need to change the style of all alert dialogs in the whole app. If you put things in one place, you save time and money :)

I agree with you, there is nothing hidden in the library   or dialog helper, just a wrappers, but what is usual is that when you don't use wrappers, you have issues :)

Comment: Good said) Thank)